# Wrong users count returned

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm seeing inconsistencies between reported ga:sessions, ga:users, ga:pageviews from a query spanning a year through the API, and the same date range from the GA website.

I've been able to match ga:sessions & ga:pageviews exactly by requesting every month separately and summing the values, however in the case of ga:users I am still seeing wildly different figures between the numbers returned by GAPI and the GA website.

The number is actually larger than the year's figures when I sum the month's figures, and both numbers are higher than the values reported in the GA website.

What dimension/metric could GA be using for 'Users'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your having an issue with [sampling level](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#samplingLevel).  If the request you are making returns a large enough amount of data in this case selecting a full years worth of data.  The server will return the results sampled.

> Sampling
>
> Google Analytics calculates certain combinations of dimensions and
>   metrics on the fly. To return the data in a reasonable time, Google
>   Analytics may only process a sample of the data.
>
> You can specify the sampling level to use for a request by setting the
>   samplingLevel parameter.
>
> If a Core Reporting API response contains sampled data, then the
>   containsSampledData response field will be true. In addition, 2
>   properties will provide information about the sampling level for the
>   query: sampleSize and sampleSpace. With these 2 values you can
>   calculate the percentage of sessions that were used for the query. For
>   example, if sampleSize is 201,000 and sampleSpace is 220,000 then the
>   report is based on (201,000 / 220,000) * 100 = 91.36%  of sessions.

When requesting from the api the Default sampleing level is used this is in order to increase speed of the request. You can change that by sending specifying the samplingLevel to use in your request.

```
samplingLevel=DEFAULT 
Optional.Use this parameter to set the sampling level (i.e. the number of sessions used
to calculate the result) for a reporting query. The allowed values are consistent with
the web interface and include: 

•DEFAULT — Returns response with a sample size that balances speed and accuracy.
•FASTER — Returns a fast response with a smaller sample size.
•HIGHER_PRECISION — Returns a more accurate response using a large sample size, but this may result in the response being slower.
```

Comment: Yes this is the absolute case - I didn't realise the API also sampled the values returned, given how slow the responses are :)

Comment: Also didn't realise I could request higher precision via the API. Should teach me to read the API and not expect the code I was using (PHP GAPI class) to be complete.

Comment: Well I've just experimented with samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION and the numbers are still wrong, for pageviews, users, sessions when querying for the whole year. I don't understand how to get an accurate number of unique users across a year's range - a fairly common request I assume?

Comment: How off are the numbers? Are you remember not to query yesterday? data under 24-48 hours old isn't accurate.

Comment: Apologies, now that I have HIGHER_PRECISION the numbers are perfect. The discrepancy was a fault of my date handling code.